# New site. Tons of traffic from Google. Nothing from Yahoo or Bing. What gives?

Tags: seo, search, startup

I've launched a number of sites recently (8-12 weeks) that are getting tons of traffic from google search at an increasing rate (both image and web), but they are getting absolutely nothing from bing or yahoo.  what gives?  what are some tricks to get yahoo and bing to send some search traffic?

Comment: Do you appear in their results?

Comment: FYI, Yahoo search is now powered by Bing.

Comment: My sites appear in search results and in 'webmaster' tools for bing and yahoo.  My sites are all targeted at engineers in manufacturing, but we for sure get a lot of "regular" people as well.. assuming ad click topics are a reasonable measure (which they may not be).

Answer (score 3):

See the webmaster tools of the sites: [Bing](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmasters/?rfp=1529310102), 
[Yahoo](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/submit).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [stackoverflow.com traffic sources in 2010](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/trouble-in-the-house-of-google.html) less than 1% of traffic comes from Bing.

Is the problem Bing/Yahoo not ranking your site well, or no-one using Bing/Yahoo?

Comment: we've been up for quite some time now, are getting great traffic from google, but still seeing almost nothing from microsoft and bing. we get a small trickle from them both. who knows...